# Dynamic class function interface/traits

Tags: php, oop

I am attempting to get something to the effect of dynamic traits.

I would like

```
class API {
    private $_source = "some text";
    public function __construct($apiSource){
        switch($apiSource){
            case "a":
                use APIa;
                break;
            case "b":
                use APIb;
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }

    public function whatAPI(){
        return "none";
    }

    public function decode(){
        return explode(" ", $this->_source);
    }
}

trait APIa {
    public function whatAPI(){
        return "APIa";
    }

    public function decode(){
        return json_decode($this->_source);
    }

    public function onlyForA(){
        return "something";
    }
}

trait APIb {
    public function whatAPI(){
        return "APIb";
    }
}
```

Where API::source is accessible to whichever (`APIa`/`APIb`) is used. It would be called like:

```
$api = new API()
$api->whatAPI(); // "none"

$api = new API("a")
$api->onlyForA(); // "something"
```

Unfortunately, the `use` can't be loaded from within a function.

In the case of `API::decode()`, `APIa` should override it, where as `APIb` should inherit it.

I've tried using a private function in `API` to hold an `apiClass`, and then using it as `$this->apiClass->func()`, but it becomes overly annoying to develop and maintain.

Comment: Why not using an abstract class in such a case? you could define an abstract class with the required methods and, according to your switch, extend that abstract class by implementing the methods you need by (eventually) overriding the existing ones.

Comment: @briosheje Do you mean having `API` as abstract, or `APIa` and `APIb`? I can't picture how that would work.

Comment: I would make API abstract and extend that abstract class with APIa and APIb, that's what I meant

Comment: @briosheje How would I then call `new API()` to select which class if it is abstract?

Comment: I personally would make an abstract class GenericApi, extend it with APIa and APIb and make another class (API, like your), which creates an inner private object ($api, perhaps) which is implemented in the construct according to the switch ase. In a nutshell, you have an abstract class, a number of classes (APIa, APIb [..]) and a generic class that you use to "create" the correct api object.

Comment: Keep in mind that I'm not a master in such an argument (I'm used to OOP, but I mostly make some pretty complex backend applications based on frameworks, where you usually "Lose" most of the complex OOP branch), however, from the example you have provided, having an abstract class is, in my hopinion, the best solution because whenever, in the future, you will need to add a method to every class, you will be able to do that directly through the abstract class. It largely depends, however, on what you're planning to do :P